# Why my question is closed after I edit it?

Tags: discussion

My [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/812754/windows-10-directory-installer-takes-too-much-space-can-i-set-it-as-compressed) was put `on hold`, because I ask it too broad. After receive bad comment from user who answered generally I apologized to him and edit question. It was already put on hold and now I see it is closed to be too broad! But I edit it to be as much specific as I think it can be.

So why my question is closed anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many issues with your question and your edits didn't make it any better. Generally, editing a question doesn't magically protect your question from being closed if the edit doesn't really improve the post.

This is all moot anyway because your question is plainly [off-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on SF. I've closed it with that reason now.

Comment: 10x, for clear explanation @Sven. I will ask my question in proper community.